# Ways to add one more quote nesting level (docker + bash + psql)

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, psql, quotes

I need to modify a value in postgreSQL table in docker using a single command. I want to run something like this inside a container:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c \"\c database_name\" -c \"UPDATE table_name SET value_name = 'value';\""
```

It turned out to  be the only way to do this because `echo "\c database_name \\ UPDATE table_name SET value_name = 'value';" | psql` doesn't work in my postgreSQL resulting in

```
invalid command \
```

Is there anything I can do to run it in a container via command `sudo docker exec -it container_name bash -c "*command above*"`? None of the quote types surrounding *command above* make it work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you run `psql` directly on the host, connecting to the database container's published port?  That would avoid most of these layers; you could even write the SQL command into a local file to avoid quoting altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid using `su` by telling `docker exec` itself which user should run `psql`. You can also run `psql` directly, rather than executing a `bash` shell that executes it.

```
sudo docker exec --user postgres \
  psql -c "\c database_name" -c "UPDATE table_name SET value_name = 'value';"
```